# Insert "Last Modified" timestamp into javadoc footer

Tags: javadoc, footer, last-modified

Is there a way to specify the last modified date of the class file? I'd like each javadoc page to have the last modified timestamp of the class file included, preferrably in the footer.

I thought I had done something like this some time ago, but can't find any examples on the web, and the documentation for footer simply indicates that it can contain html. So can it not have any kind of place holder that will be set when the javadoc is generated?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Some source control systems allow you to code a marker that's updated when you commit the file. If you put that inside javadoc, the javadoc will tell you the revision number and when it was last committed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this feature is available in javadoc. Why don't you rely on the source control to do this work for you? You can have, if SVN, defined keywords that will automatically be filled upon commit (see [svn propset](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch07s02.html)). This is much better and you don't need to worry about the javadoc processing.

If a simpler approach can satisfy, you may just add a script into the bottom option, like:

```
-bottom "<font size=\"-1\">Created by `echo $USER`, at `date +%Y-%m-%d\ %H:%M:%S.%N`.</font>"
```

Comment: Note that this example is using Unix/Bash, but you can easily adapt to Windows/DOS.

Comment: This will put the last date of javadoc generation, not the last modification date of each class.

Comment: So you rely on a SVN proposet to do this for you... No command in javadoc options will allow you to dynamically place the date of each file being processed, it just becomes a static string (or we could be using the command `stat` for that).

Answer (score 0):

I think it is the job of the editor to write the time stamp into the code. This is how [Emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) does it:

```
package my.tuple;

/**
 * Implementation of an ordered 2-tuple.
 *
 * @date 2013-07-03
 */

public class Pair<A,B>
{
}

// Local Variables:
// time-stamp-pattern: "0/^ \\* @date %:y-%02m-%02d$"
// End:
```

After that the document processor can read the date. But the standard javadoc is not aware of dates. You need Eclipse or Doxygen for this.